# Capture text between two tokens

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to get the text between two tokens.

For example, let's say the text is:

```
arn:aws:dfasdfasdf/asdfa:start:CaptureThis/end
```

The output should be: `CaptureThis`

And the two tokens are: `:start:` and `/end`

The closest I could get was using this *regex*:

```
INPUT="arn:aws:dfasdfasdf/asdfa:start:CaptureThis/end"
VALUE=$(echo "${INPUT}" | sed -e 's/:start:\(.*\)\/end/\1/')
```

... but this returns most of the string:  `arn:aws:dfasdfasdf/asdfa:start:CaptureThis/end`

**How do I get all of the other text out of the way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's/^.*:start:\(.*\)\/end.*$/\1/' <<<'arn:aws:dfasdfasdf/asdfa:start:CaptureThis/end'
CaptureThis
```

The problem with your approach was that you only replaced *part* of the input line, because your regex didn't capture the *entire* line.

Note how the command above anchors the regex both at the beginning of the line (`^.*`) and at the end (`.*$`) so as to ensure that the entire line is matched and thus replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You could use (GNU) grep with Perl regular expressions (look-arounds) and the `-o` option to only return the match:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=:start:).*(?=/end)' <<< 'arn:aws:dfasdfasdf/asdfa:start:CaptureThis/end'
CaptureThis
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use :

```
VALUE=$(echo "${INPUT}" | sed -e 's/.*:start:\(.*\)\/end.*/\1/')
```

If the tokens are liable to change, you could use variables - but since "/end" has a "/", that could lead to sed getting confused, so you'd probably want to change its delimiter to some non-conflicting character (like a "?"), so :

```
TOKEN1=":start:"
TOKEN2="/end"
VALUE=$(echo "${INPUT}" | sed -e "s?.*$TOKEN1\(.*\)$TOKEN2.*?\1?")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for any external utilities, bash *parameter-expansion* will handle it all for you:

```
INPUT="arn:aws:dfasdfasdf/asdfa:start:CaptureThis/end"
token=${INPUT##*:}
echo ${token%/*}
```

**Output**

```
CaptureThis
```

Comment: You probably mean _external_ utilities (as opposed to shell builtins / native features) rather than "3rd party". Note that the OP is asking for the substring bookended by `:start:` and `/end`, which is only _incidentally_ the same as your solution. As an aside: `**` is probably a typo; `*` is enough.

Comment: Yes, your are correct. Just bad verbiage on my part.